# Blank background-image in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

For a website, i want 70% of the page to be covered with an image. However the image is just blank.
I use Vue.js as my frontend. Here is the code that results in a blank space:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from 'vue';
</script>


<template>

  <div style="background-image: `url(${require('../assets/bg.png')})`;
            height: 70vh" class="full-width-image">
    </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <p>test test test!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template> -

  <style>
  .full-width-image {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;

  }
  </style>
```

Here is how the site looks like: [image]

Comment: What is the question exactly ???
In addition, why do you use an image to create a white background ? 
Using css (background-color: white) should do the triks

Comment: why put code in a snippet that doesn't, and can never, run?

Comment: @DavidROSEY Sorry my question was a bit misleading, i dont want a white background, instead i want my image to be shown as background. However, my image is blank (shown in the picture provided). Boussadjra Brahim answer worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the image as module then bind it to the style background :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from 'vue';
import bg from '../assets/bg.png'

</script>


<template>

  <div :style="{'background-image': url(bg), height: '70vh'}" class="full-width-image">
    </di
    ...
    </div>
</template>
```